# Wordpress htaccess redirect with rewriterule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website where I want to redirect the tag-page URL's to a specific post.

This works in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /tag/hometrainer/ https://www.mywebsite.nl/beste-hometrainer-test
```

The problem is that when I append '/page/2/' (for example) to the initial url, it is also appended to the redirect url:
https://www.mywebsite.nl/tag/hometrainer/page/2/ redirects to https://www.mywebsite.nl/beste-hometrainer-test/page/2, it should redirect to https://www.mywebsite.nl/beste-hometrainer-test

So I need a "catch all" for everything after "/tag/hometrainer" and this should not be displayed in the redirect url.

This does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^/tag/hometrainer(.*)$ /beste-hometrainer-test [R=301,L]
```

I get the "post not found" page.

Comment: When configured in .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against, never starts with a slash - that has been stripped off at this point already.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `?` Add the end of URL to remove any query strings

```
RewriteRule ^/tag/hometrainer(.*)$ /beste-hometrainer-test? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Does not work, I still get "page not found".

Comment: @yesterday `Redirect 301 /tag/hometrainer/ https://www.mywebsite.nl/beste-hometrainer-test?` Please try this.

Comment: nope it just adds a '?' in the url bar.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the below code -

```
RewriteRule ^/from-slug(.*)$ /to-slug? [R=301,L]
```